# VBScript Doesn't insert copied Excel into Word on specific Page

Tags: excel, ms-word, vbscript

I try to copy a part from Excel into word on a specific (fifth) page.
It copies the excel part into word, but always on the first page.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
Set objwdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objSelection = objwdapp.Selection

objExcel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy
'Declare Object variables for the Word application and file or document
Dim wddoc
'Declare a String variable for the file name and folder path
Dim strdocname
'error handling is extremely important in making Excel work with Word
On Error Resume Next
'GetObject needs two parameters. The first is optional
Set objwdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then
Err.Clear
'we create a new instance of MS Word
Set objwdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
'Our application is made visible
objwdapp.Visible = True
strdocname = "C:\test.docx"
'we activate our MS Word instance
objwdapp.Activate
Set wddoc = objwdapp.Documents(strdocname)
'we open MS Word file if it is not open
If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = objwdapp.Documents.Open(strdocname)
wddoc.Activate
'''''' this doesn't work''''''
objSelection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 5
objSelection.TypeText "Test"
wddoc.Range.Paste
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
wddoc.SaveAs("C:\test1.docx")
objwdapp.Quit
'Here we free memory allocated to our two object variables
Set wddoc = Nothing
Set objwdapp = Nothing
'The following line of code removes the selection of range A1:D4 in Excel
Application.CutCopyMode = False
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit
```

I also tried to insert the Excel part after a specific word, e.g.:

```
objSelection.InsertAfter "testing"
```

It also pastes the part in the first page.
Has somebody an idea?

Comment: Code is using `objwdapp` and `wdapp` as word application objects. Use only one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint, but unfortunately it still puts the Excel table on the first page.

Comment: Can you [edit] and add your current code?

Comment: Sure, is done :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is overly verbose. Amongst other things, it tries to create a Word instance *twice*. All you need is:

```
Set ObjXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ObjWkBk = ObjXl.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")

Set ObjWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set ObjDoc = ObjWd.Documents.Open("C:\test.docx")

ObjWkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy
ObjDoc.Range.GoTo(1, 1, 5).GoTo(-1, , , "\page").Paste
ObjDoc.SaveAs ("C:\test1.docx")

ObjDoc.Close: ObjWd.Quit: ObjWkBk.Close: ObjXl.Quit
Set ObjDoc = Nothing: Set ObjWd = Nothing: Set ObjWkBk = Nothing: Set ObjXl = Nothing
```

Comment: It would be good if you explain what `ObjDoc.Range.GoTo(1, 1, 5).GoTo(-1, , , "\page").Paste` does

Comment: That may well be true, but your answer depends heavilly on that detail.  It's not much to ask to explain it in the answer

Comment: Could you also give me a hint how I use the "InsertAfter"? I tried some suggestions, but I don't get it.

Comment: Kindly post a new question for that, explaining how you propose to use it.

Comment: Sure, here is my question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67581314/vbscript-doesnt-insert-copied-excel-into-word-after-specific-word) Would be glad if you can help :)!