# VBScript Doesn't insert copied Excel into Word after specific word

Tags: excel, ms-word, vbscript

I tried to insert a a copied Excel part after a specific word.
Unfortunately it's not working.

```
        Set ObjXl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set ObjWkBk = ObjXl.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
        
        Set ObjWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set ObjDoc = ObjWd.Documents.Open("C:\test.docx")
        
        ObjWkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy

        #############Here I have Problems############
        ObjDoc.Range.InsertAfter("Ending").Paste
        #############################################

        ObjDoc.SaveAs ("C:\test1.docx")
        
        ObjDoc.Close: ObjWd.Quit: ObjWkBk.Close: ObjXl.Quit
        Set ObjDoc = Nothing: Set ObjWd = Nothing: Set ObjWkBk = Nothing: Set ObjXl = Nothing
```

Could you help?

Comment: Kindly don't use the [word] tag for [ms-word] questions. At stated at the top of the [word] tag page: «A word is the amount of data that a processor can fit in its general-purpose registers ... Programming-related questions concerning Microsoft Word should NOT use this tag»

Comment: Alright, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use .InsertAfter that way - as Word's Help file would readily show. Instead you need to Find the 'Ending' text, then Paste after that. For example:

```
With ObjDoc
  With .Range
    .Find.Execute "Ending", True, True, False, , , True, 0
    .Collapse 0
    .Paste
  End With
  .SaveAs ("C:\test1.docx")
  .Close
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

An Excel *Range* is a different animal from a Word *Range*. Start by declaring variables for each, like ...

```
Dim xlRange as Excel.Range
Dim wdRange as Word.Range
```

Now you would be able to assign the Excel range to `xlRange`.

```
Set xlRange =  ObjWkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4")
```

And you could do the same for your Word range.

```
Set wdRange = ObjDoc.Range("Ending")
```

You can probably see that this doesn't look right, and to enable this judgment is the object of this exercise. In Word a range is defined by the position of its first and last characters in the document. If the range is named, it's called a *Bookmark*. So, if you have a bookmark by the name of *"Ending"* then the correct assignment would look like ...

```
Set wdRange = ObjDoc.Bookmarks("Ending").Range
```

Assuming that this range includes the text between character 1111 and 1122, then collapsing that range to its end would create `Range(1122, 1123)` and at that point you can insert **text** (because it's a Word document) by a number of methods.

The problem is that your `xlRange` isn't text. It's an array of 16 Excel cells, each of them endowed with many properties. Depending upon how you copy this range into Word, you may force the conversion of Excel cells to a Word table. Bear in mind that a Word table doesn't have all the properties of an Excel table or an Excel array of cells. It's differently structured and not all properties are transferrable but you will get a table.

On the other hand, if your intention is to take the text from `xlRange` and insert it into Word as text then you would have to first extract the text from each cell, create a string, and then paste that string into the Word document at the location defined by `wdRange`. In this regard it's noteworthy that VBA *Strings* are interchangeable. You can create a string by extracting text from Excel cells and paste that same string to a Word document without worrying about Excel and Word types of `Strings`.

Comment: Okay, that's a quite nice alternative and for my use case a better one. I didn't know this Option exists.